# Internet access with Android M

Tags: java, android, http

I'm trying to do HTTP requests in Anrdoid M. But every time I get the error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

As far as I know every app has the Internet permission by default in Android M. So why does this error occur?

I also tried adding the permission to my manifest and to get a runtime permission, but both without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You've done something wrong.  Show all the relevant code and manifest that you think should work but does not work.

Comment: Have you declared permission like this : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I have added the manifest to my post.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know every APp has INTERNET permission by default in Android M

No, they do not.

> So why does this error occur?

Apparently, you do not have the `<uses-permission>` element, or [it is in the wrong spot](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html).

> and to get a runtime permission

The `INTERNET` permission is not `dangerous` and so does not require with the runtime permission system.

Answer (score 2):

You must write the permission outside the application tag

> 

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the specific android.permission.INTERNET permission, it is still mandatory for apps that will access the Internet. If a developer were to publish an app without defining it in the Android manifest, an exception will be thrown the first time a connection attempt is made, and the app will possibly crash. This is no different than before.

So you can check in your manifest the permition for internet and network state

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You must have the Internet permission in order to get access to the internet.
Use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
where I showed.